# Can I use data- attribute in a text link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this:

```
<a class="mylink" href="#" data-jSearchType="Category" data-jSearchValue="misc">Miscellaneous</a>
<a class="mylink" href="#" data-jSearchType="Category" data-jSearchValue="miscThis">Miscellaneous1</a>
<a class="mylink" href="#" data-jSearchType="Category" data-jSearchValue="miscThat">Miscellaneous2</a>
<a class="mylink" href="#" data-jSearchType="OtherCategory" data-jSearchValue="miscOther">Miscellaneous3</a>
```

and I want it to work with this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.mylink').click(function () {
var myvalue1 = $('. mylink').index.(this).data-jSearchType;
var myvalue2 = $('. mylink').index.(this).data-jSearchValue;
$('<form action="mylinkReceiver.php" method="POST"/>')
    .append($('<input type="text" name="d" value="' + myvalue1 + '"> <input type="text" name="v" value="' + myvalue2 + '">'))
    .appendTo($(document.body))
    .submit();
});
});
```

Clicking on the link should set "myvalue1" and "myvalue2", which are then the values in the submitted form.

I've seen several examples of this that worked, but in my arrangement the variables remain undefined.

And now my head hurts…

Maybe this question is more clear with the additional links involved

Comment: try with -> var myvalue1 = $(this).attr('data-jSearchType');

Comment: also, in the html, where is the class "mylink"?

Comment: The main problem is he was using `.mylink`  instead of `.golink` so his JS did not match the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/4Spgg/)**</kbd>

You have invalid data attributes containing capital letters and about accessing data attributes with jQuery it should be `.data('attributename')`

```
<a class="mylink" href="#" data-type="Category" data-value="misc">Miscellaneous</a>
```

---

```
$(function() {
  $('.mylink').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var myvalue1 = $(this).data('type'),
        myvalue2 = $(this).data('value');

    $('<form action="mylinkReceiver.php" method="POST">' +
      '<input type="text" name="d" value="' + myvalue1 + '">' +
      '<input type="text" name="v" value="' + myvalue2 + '">' +
      '</form>').appendTo($('body')).submit();
  });
});
```

***Note:** If you prefer you could use `data-jsearch-type` & `data-jsearch-value` then acces it with e.g. `$(this).data('jsearch-type')`

Also for this you could use span instead of anchor e.g.

```
<span class="mylink" data-type="Category" data-value="misc">Miscellaneous</span>
```

then style it with CSS

```
.mylink {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #0098f4;
}
.mylink:hover {
  color: #666;
}
```

in that case you don't need to prevent default action in script.

Comment: This first part will work not I think  $('<form action="mylinkReceiver.php" method="POST"/>') may need to be replaced with  $('form')    as jQuery selector will try to find that string and will fail.

Comment: @Daveo I've change it a little.

Comment: @Daveo - There were a lot of other errors, but this helped point me in the right direction. It's a bit slow responding for some reason, but it sends the two values perfectly. Thanks so much.